# Two questions about the scene that took place in Florida

Tags: plot-explanation, donnie-brasco

When Lefty and Sonnie Black were sitting beside the swimming pool. There were lines like this:

01:09:03 What are you doing? You want to throw me in the pool? You got the balls?

01:09:07 He hasn't made a pick yet.

01:09:09 Forget those dogs.

1. When someone say "dogs" , is the script wrong ? Because I think what he tries to say is "dorks"
2. When Lefty said

> They see you in that fucking shirt , they say , " There's Joe Faccia
>   Di Cula," in that shirt . Look at him , that was once yellow , that
>   shirt .

Does that mean his shirt is very dirty or what ? And who's Joe Faccia Di Cula ?

Comment: you really didn't get this movie

Comment: Just a few scenes ~~ HAHA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The picks he was talking about were bets on dogs, literally.  He was betting on dog races.

2) Yes, he's making fun of the shirt being dirty, because it's been worn so often.  "Joe Faccia Di Cula" is like "Joey Bag-a-donuts".  It's like a reference to a stereotypical Italian.

Comment: 1.Then when Lefty said " You want to throw me in the pool? You got the balls? " He was talking about what ? He was talking about losing the bet ?                                                 2. So the term of "Joe Faccia Di Cula" is coming from  "Joey Bag-a-donuts" ? It seems like they have the same meaning .

Comment: "You want to throw me in the pool?" is just banter.  Not every line in every movie has meaning.  They were sitting next to the pool, so the context makes sense.  As for Joe Faccia Di Culo, that last name is literally translated to "Ass Face".  It's meant to be derogatory.